# DrawRectangle SharpDX

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I have a screen overlay setup for my program. I'm trying to draw a box with a blue line in this overlay window and I'm trying to use SharpDX to do it.

```
device.FillRectangle(new RectangleF(300, 300, 400, 200), backgroundBrush);
```

The only question I have is how to use the brush value for fillRectangle.

In the brush class it's asking me for a IntPtr and even if I do:

```
device.FillRectangle(new RectangleF(300, 300, 400, 200),SharpDX.Direct2D1.Brush(IntPtr.Zero);
```

It still throws errors.

Here's the documentation.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/SharpDX.Direct2D1/SharpDX.Direct2D1/Brush

Comment: `IntPtr.Zero` won't cut it. You need a pointer to a native brush. `Zero` is a null pointer.

Comment: @Sefe What should I use for the brush then?

Comment: I don't know sharpdx, but it asks for the native pointer of the brush. You need to get it first to create the brush instance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you create one of the subclasses of Brush (probably SolidColorBrush in this case?).

Something like this:

```
DrawingBrush = new SolidColorBrush(RenderTarget, Color.Black);
```

Where RenderTarget is the RenderTarget you created to draw to.